# Jquery delay timeout function?

Tags: jquery, timeout, delay

I am really struglling tring to get this to work what i what is if my php script returns success.

echo success

I want it to should a message that says congratulations its all setup but stay for aleast 5 seconds but it never seems to work i have tried elay etc but still getting issues please help.

here is my code it works but for about a second it then redirects far to quick to read it.

```
 if($.trim(data) == 'Congratulations'){
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#congrats').fadeIn(1000,function(){
        window.location.href='http://example.co.uk/tour/first-time-users';
    });
},5500);
```

Comment: That code you've got will fade in the element "congrats" after five and a half seconds. What doesn't work?  What are the "issues"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **think** that what you need is:

```
if($.trim(data) == 'Congratulations') {
    $('#congrats').fadeIn(1000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://example.co.uk/tour/first-time-users';
    }, 5500);
}
```

This will show the `congrats` div with animation effect then rediret after 5.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be helpful :)

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#congrats').fadeIn(1000, function(){
        window.location = 'http://www.examle.com';
    }}
}, 5500);
```

The timeout needs its own delay.

Comment: i dont want congrats to fadeIn for 5 secs i want it to show immediately but wait 5 secs before the page redirects.

Answer (score 0):

set time out expects a string as the function...

try

```
if($.trim(data) == 'Congratulations'){
    setTimeout("function(){
        $('#congrats').fadeIn(1000,function(){
            window.location.href='http://example.co.uk/tour/first-time-users';
        });
    }",5500);
}
```

Comment: Why do people still keep passing in strings into the setTimeout funciton? I see this so often.

Comment: That's a terrible bad practice. Please don't even recommend it.

Comment: @Šime Vidas gooood question ... some weird mix between lambda and giving the function name

Answer (score 0):

The better option I think is:

```
if($.trim(data) == 'Congratulations'){
    $('#congrats').fadeIn(1000, function() { setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href='http://example.co.uk/tour/first-time-users';
    }, 5000)});
}
```